# What is the best way to get all my categories in my mongodb collection of posts

Tags: mongodb, express

I am working on a blog application using Express, MongoDB, and React. I'm definitely more comfortable working with a relational DB, but I want to be more comfortable in document based DB so here I am.

I have a post collection in its current state looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "001",
        "category": "fishing",
        "title": "jigs",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu"
    },
    {
        "id": "002",
        "category": "cooking",
        "title": "tuna casserole",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"
    },
...]
```

when you go to **url/posts** you'll get all the posts when you go to **url/posts/cooking** you get cooking of course.

When I was working on the front end with stubbed data I was making a categories list from a json file like so:

```
const uniqueCategories = [
    ...new Set(props.posts.map((post) => post.category)),
];
```

However, I'm fetching my posts by category like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPosts() {
        fetch(`api/posts/${category}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setPosts(result);
                    console.log('result', result);
                }
            );
    }
    fetchPosts();
}, [category]);
```

I haven't implemented the **all** categories yet, but it doesn't matter. Right now, if I get cooking category, my uniqueCategories func above will only be mapping **cooking**

So the question is. What is the best way to architect this?

Should I have a categories collection? In the posts collection, should I reference an id of categories collection?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your application and its queries.

#### Option 1

If you only want to get all posts category, you can just index your category and use [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method. The cons of this is you can't add additional field for the category, for example the category description.

Code example:

```js
db.posts.createIndex({ category: 1 }); // create index for category field

db.posts.distinct("category") // ["fishing", "cooking"]
```

#### Option 2

Create category collection:

```js
{
   _id: "fishing",
   ...
}
```

You don't need to use MongoDB default ObjectId as the `_id`, since the category name will be unique, you can just set the category name as the `_id`, this also allows you to get posts category name without doing any additional lookup. With this option, you can add additional field for the category, for example:

```js
{
   _id: "fishing",
   name: "Fishing",
   description: "Category for all of the fishing lovers!"
}
```

Then on your `post` collection, you can just use the category `_id` as the category value

```js
{
  "id": "001",
  "category": "fishing",
  "title": "jigs",
  "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu"
},
```

And if you want to get list of category, you can just query to category collection instead.